# Combining multiple JSON arrays using WSO2 aggregator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm trying to combine two different data sources into a single data feed using WSO2 ESB. Because the different sources have different data formats my approach has been to create a proxy for each endpoint to deal with authorisation and payload formatting so that both return a JSON array. Based on research my assumption was that I could then to use the aggregator mediaor to combine the results. After working through lots of examples I have combined the two arrays successfully however one of the arrays is always duplicated. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong or does anyone have any other suggestions about a better way of achieving the combination of two JSON arrays?

I have set up the following code examples to simulate 2 feeds and then combine with my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="testb_url1" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable"
  transports="https http" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <target>
    <inSequence>
          <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>[
            {"id": "1",
            "type": "object",
            "name": "first"},
            {"id": "2",
            "type": "object",
            "name": "second"}
            ]
            </format>
        <args/>
      </payloadFactory>
      <log level="full"/>
      <loopback/>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
      <send/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence/>
  </target>
</proxy>
```

URL number 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="testb_url2" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable"
  transports="https http" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <target>
    <inSequence>
          <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>[
            {"id": "10",
            "type": "object",
            "name": "ten"},
            {"id": "11",
            "type": "object",
            "name": "eleven"}
            ]
            </format>
        <args/>
      </payloadFactory>
      <log level="full"/>
      <loopback/>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
      <send/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence/>
  </target>
</proxy>
```

Code to combine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="testb_combine" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable"
  transports="https http" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <target>
    <inSequence>
         <property name="enclosing_element" scope="default">
            <jsonArray xmlns=""/>
         </property>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <recipientlist>
                  <endpoint>
                     <address uri="http://localhost:8280/services/testb_url1/" trace="disable"/>
                  </endpoint>
                  <endpoint>
                     <address uri="http://localhost:8280/services/testb_url2/" trace="disable"/>
                  </endpoint>
               </recipientlist>
            </endpoint>
         </send>    
    </inSequence>
     <outSequence>
         <enrich>
            <source clone="true" xpath="$body/jsonArray/jsonElement"/>
            <target action="child" xpath="$ctx:enclosing_element"/>
         </enrich>
         <aggregate>
            <completeCondition>
               <messageCount min="-1" max="-1"/>
            </completeCondition>
            <onComplete expression="$body/jsonArray/jsonElement"
                        enclosingElementProperty="enclosing_element">
               <send/>
            </onComplete>
         </aggregate>
      </outSequence>
    <faultSequence/>
  </target>
</proxy>
```

And returned results showing data from URL 1 duplicated:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "type": "object",
    "name": "first"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "type": "object",
    "name": "second"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "type": "object",
    "name": "first"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "type": "object",
    "name": "second"
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "type": "object",
    "name": "ten"
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "type": "object",
    "name": "eleven"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the enrich mediator in the outsequence and it work like you want:
Proxy service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="testb_combine"
       transports="https http"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="enclosing_element" scope="default">
            <jsonArray xmlns=""/>
         </property>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <recipientlist>
                  <endpoint>
                     <address uri="http://localhost:8283/services/testb_url1/"/>
                  </endpoint>
                  <endpoint>
                     <address uri="http://localhost:8283/services/testb_url2/"/>
                  </endpoint>
               </recipientlist>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <aggregate>
            <completeCondition>
               <messageCount min="-1" max="-1"/>
            </completeCondition>
            <onComplete expression="$body/jsonArray/jsonElement"
                        enclosingElementProperty="enclosing_element">
               <send/>
            </onComplete>
         </aggregate>
      </outSequence>
      <faultSequence/>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

Response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "object",
        "name": "first"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "type": "object",
        "name": "second"
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "type": "object",
        "name": "ten"
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "type": "object",
        "name": "eleven"
    }
]
```